# TensorFlow.js PoseNet model keypoints animation

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, neural-network, pose-estimation, keypoint

I'm using [TensorFlow.js pre-trained PoseNet model](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet) to collect and store **pose data** from my web app. I already have some chunk of JSON with keypoints data I want to analyze to use it as training set for another neural network. Here's the keypoints data example:

```js
 "keypoints": [
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 76.291801452637,
        "x": 253.36747741699
      },
      "part": "nose",
      "score": 0.99539834260941
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 71.10383605957,
        "x": 253.54365539551
      },
      "part": "leftEye",
      "score": 0.98781454563141
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 71.839515686035,
        "x": 246.00454711914
      },
      "part": "rightEye",
      "score": 0.99528175592422
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 72.848854064941,
        "x": 263.08151245117
      },
      "part": "leftEar",
      "score": 0.84029853343964
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 79.956565856934,
        "x": 234.26812744141
      },
      "part": "rightEar",
      "score": 0.92544466257095
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 98.34538269043,
        "x": 399.64068603516
      },
      "part": "leftShoulder",
      "score": 0.99559044837952
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 95.082359313965,
        "x": 458.21868896484
      },
      "part": "rightShoulder",
      "score": 0.99583911895752
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 94.626205444336,
        "x": 163.94561767578
      },
      "part": "leftElbow",
      "score": 0.9518963098526
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 150.2349395752,
        "x": 245.06030273438
      },
      "part": "rightElbow",
      "score": 0.98052614927292
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 113.9603729248,
        "x": 393.19735717773
      },
      "part": "leftWrist",
      "score": 0.94009721279144
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 186.47859191895,
        "x": 257.98034667969
      },
      "part": "rightWrist",
      "score": 0.98029226064682
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 208.5266418457,
        "x": 284.46710205078
      },
      "part": "leftHip",
      "score": 0.97870296239853
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 209.9910736084,
        "x": 243.31219482422
      },
      "part": "rightHip",
      "score": 0.97424703836441
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 281.61965942383,
        "x": 310.93188476562
      },
      "part": "leftKnee",
      "score": 0.98368924856186
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 282.80120849609,
        "x": 203.81164550781
      },
      "part": "rightKnee",
      "score": 0.96947449445724
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 360.62716674805,
        "x": 292.21047973633
      },
      "part": "leftAnkle",
      "score": 0.8883239030838
    },
    {
      "position": {
        "y": 347.41177368164,
        "x": 203.88229370117
      },
      "part": "rightAnkle",
      "score": 0.8255187869072
    }
  ]
```

The problem is that **I need an interface to display that data**, perfectly if it would be a web app interface. I've only found [Google's demo app](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/demos/posenet/camera.html) using PoseNet model with the keypoints attached on top of webcam video that is displayed in a `<canvas/>`, but it seems that it uses some manual canvas drawing.

So I'm interested, **are there some libraries or non-JS tools for viewing the keypoints data** as animated keyframes or maybe manually sliding between them? Or do I have to implement that myself? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this repo: https://github.com/ajaichemmanam/Posenet-ReactWebapp. It uses react to make a webapp for displaying posenet keypoints.

Comment: That's possibly the same thing as the google demo. But thanks, I'll check if I can easily extract canvas drawing from it.